# Maintain authorization status

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, openshift

I'm working on a web service based Tomcat app that does exclusively JAX-RS type RESTful API's.  There's a concept of authorization as determined by a header.  Depending on what role a person has, they see more or less of something, but usually they see at least part of something.  For example, there's a service that gives a list of categories. Almost everyone will have access to it, but not everyone sees all categories.
There's a method which does a database call to get the what the user is entitled to see, but that takes about 200ish ms.  I'd like to do this once and store it in some sort of session.  But again, this is JAXRS, and I used to think state isn't maintained.  Can I just do the entitlement checks once, store the resulting object in the HttpSession? Would I need to do anything to Tomcat/OpenShift and others to maintain this?  I don't think sessions hop between locations on the OpenShift load balancer.

I saw code like this:

```
@Provider
public class AuthenticationFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
...
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic"
```

But I don't know if this is applicable in all JAX-RS type situations.  Right now, I don't even know what sort of authorization scheme is implemented once it's deployed.

I'm not looking for an complete answer, but rather a helpful place to start and things to avoid.  I won't have much room for mistakes if something doesn't work when it gets deployed, especially to prod.

Answer (score 1):

In the environment I tested in (Wildfly/RestEasy) this can work.  I too have a `ContainerRequestFilter` that creates a custom Principal.  And in my service code I use `@RolesAllowed`.  However, with my normal `ContainerRequestFilter` I see that the responses have no Cookie set and when I come back in with another request I have to go through the `filter` method again.  So, to your point, in this context you are totally stateless.

However, if I add:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
```

to my `ContainerRequestFilter` and access the session id in my `filter` method I can see that the response now has a JSESSIONID cookie.  A repeat call, with the Cookie, gives me back the same `HttpSession`.  In my services I added a `@Context HttpServletRequest request` to my method and with that I can access the session and something that is more stateful.

I'll leave it to the REST philosophers to decide if this now stateful code is a good idea but, as long as the client you're using handles Cookies correctly, you could calculate the roles the user is in in your `filter` method (checking the session first to see if they already exist) and then access them in your JAX-RS method.

Comment: @stdunar I can add this HttpServletRequest to the API methods (there's no Spring to set this), I can then build the entitlement object and save it to the session if it's not already there.  Let me be dumb for a moment, I assume that subsequent calls by the Angular code would need to save this JSESSIONID cookie, right? There's multiple Tomcat instances running, but I don't know if it shares the session.

Comment: I'll admit I haven't worked with Angular since the 1.x days and there was a flag needed back then on the call to send cookies.  Normally the browser would do this for you and I'm not sure if it will or not.  If there are multiple Tomcat instances they may be behind a load balancer and it should handle this for you.  But the key will be the cookie and it's pretty easy to see that with the browser debug tools.